# sql - Update record using inner join

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-update, inner-join

I am working on system, where I have to update a field ***dupstat*** for duplicate records based on 4 columns i.e. ***cname, fname, mname, dob***. Also I have to check if ***eligibility*** column contains value "No". I have following query to find out duplicate records:

```
select o.cname, o.fname, o.CRollNo, o.Coll_Code, o.mname, o.dob, oc.dupeCount, o.Eligible, o.dupstat
from REGN_Temp o
inner join (
    SELECT cname, COUNT(*) AS dupeCount, FName, mname, dob
    FROM REGN_Temp
    GROUP BY cname, FName, mname,dob
    HAVING COUNT(*) > 1
) oc on o.cname = oc.cname and o.fname = oc.FName and o.mname = oc.mname and o.dob=oc.dob and o.Eligible='No' order by cname, fname
```

Now I want to update column "***dupstat***=Y" for all the records which are duplicate and having ***eligibility*** = "NO"

Answer (score 4):

You can [`UPDATE`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms177523.aspx) with `JOIN` directly, just use `UPDATE` instead of `SELECT` followed by the `SET` like this:

```
UPDATE o
SET o.dupstat='Y'
from REGN_Temp o
inner join 
(
    SELECT cname, COUNT(*) AS dupeCount, FName, mname, dob
    FROM REGN_Temp
    GROUP BY cname, FName, mname,dob
    HAVING COUNT(*) > 1
) oc on o.cname = oc.cname 
  and o.fname = oc.FName
  and o.mname = oc.mname 
  and o.dob=oc.dob 
  and o.Eligible='No'
```